# Centering Bootstrap 4 pills to align over each other on small screens

Tags: alignment, bootstrap-4, nav-pills

Is there a built-in Bootstrap 4 trick that will align these three to centre, in a line "on a large screen", with a small space between them, then place them over each other when displayed on a small screen?

```
 <h4 class="h4">Follow Social Media</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6-lg col-4-md col-1-sm center-pills">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-tabs">
              <a class="nav-link  active social social_f" href="#">Facebook</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-tabs">
              <a class="nav-link active social social_i" href="#">Instagram</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-tabs">
              <a class="nav-link active social social_y" href="#">Youtube</a>
            </li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
      </row>
```

I've tried adding custom css but it keeps falling apart and looks messy.

At the moment, the code above output this:
[image]

Comment: It is far from clear what exactly you want at what screen size. If you are only concerned with "small screens", then why do you have `md` and `lg` classes in there?

Comment: It's because it needs to be responsive across all screens...

Comment: OK, then it might be a good idea to describe in your question what that "being responsive" means for those other screen sizes, no?

Comment: sorry, was in a bit of a rush cooking tea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a build in bootstrap 4 trick that will align these three to centre

One of the first tricks is to use Bootstrap classes that actually exist.

`col-6-lg col-4-md col-1-sm` classes **don't exist**.

The next best trick is to replace your `nav-tabs` class with `nav-item` because the `nav-tabs` class isn't designed to be used the way you attempted to.

The `mx-auto` class needs to be added to the column to center it.

Finally, adding `nav-justified` to the parent element will do the trick of spreading the pills evenly. And for padding, you can use responsive padding classes `px-lg-3 p-md-2 p-1`.

Click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-5 col-6 text-center mx-auto">
            <h4 class="h4">Follow Social Media</h4>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li class="nav-item px-lg-3 p-md-2 p-1">
                    <a class="nav-link active social social_f" href="#">Facebook</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-lg-3 p-md-2 p-1">
                    <a class="nav-link active social social_i" href="#">Instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-lg-3 p-md-2 p-1">
                    <a class="nav-link active social social_y" href="#">Youtube</a>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but I was asking for "these three in the centre". I can already add them to the left. This is the reason for asking

Comment: Why are you then confining them in a small column??

Comment: Its a landing page. It could be accessed by any device; desktop, tablet or mobile. If the visitor lands with a mobile, the three pills need to be prominent, keeping no less than 200px width, stretched across the screen, either in a clear defined line, or stacked above each other. The small screen would require them to be stacked above, but they aren't centred.

Comment: Ok, the key word here is 'centre' as in the middle of the page

Comment: The `mx-auto` class needs to be added to the column to center it.

Comment: YAY! It's nearly there. a couple of pixels out, but it looks much better. What is the 'p' short for??

Comment: If the buttons are too large on large screens, change `col-lg-12` to `col-lg-8`.  `p` is for padding: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Thanks for this. I was dragged kicking and screaming into bs4. I prefer the good ol' fashion css3, meticulously ordering every item, but the boss said I have to learn this new futuristic stuff - thanks again ;)

Comment: You can use the responsive padding and margin classes to adjust for each screen size exactly as you need.